# Simple random walk two properties

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

First suppose that $X_1,...,X_t$ are IID random variables and $P(X_1=1)=p, P(X_1=-1)=1-p=q$ for $p\in (0,1)$, then $S_t=X_1+...+X_t, S_0=0$ is the simple random walk. I have two questions:

(1) Why are $A_t=(\frac{q}{p})^{S_t}$ and $N_t=S_t-E[S_t]$ martingales w.r.t to filtration $\sigma(X_1,...,X_t)$?

I make the standard approach: $E[A_{t+1}|F_t]=E[(\frac{q}{p})^{S_t}(\frac{q}{p})^{X_{t+1}}| F_t]=(\frac{q}{p})^{S_t}E[(\frac{q}{p})^{X_{t+1}}| F_t]$ Why should tthe last term be 1?

$E[N_{t+1}|F_t]=S_t-E[E[S_{t+1}]|F_t]$. Using tower property does not lead us to 
$E[E[S_{t+1}]|F_t]=E[S_t]$

(2) Why is the martingale $S^\tau$ not converging in $L^1$ where $\tau=\inf_\{t\in\mathbb Z^+: S_t=0\}$ is a stopping time? In this case we assume that that $S_0=1$

I have no idea here.

Comment: "Why is the martingale Sτ not converging in L1 where τ is a stopping time?" This cannot hold for every stopping time. Please specify τ.

Comment: See my comment on Giwrgos Pap, I think this should answer your question.

Comment: I am afraid it does not. For the specific stopping time τ you defined in your comment, there is convergence in $L^1$ (and in every $L^p$).

Comment: Ok, I think I used the wrong stopping time, what about $\tau:=\inf\{t\in\mathbb Z^+: S_t=0\}$?

Comment: Please make your question complete once and for all instead of forcing the readers to chase for a setting where it makes sense.

Comment: I edited my starting post.

Comment: Then the answer to (2) is trivial: because $E[S^\tau_n]=1$ for every $n$ while $E[S_\tau]=0$.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are assuming. That every stopping time is one of those you consider is wrong. That the times you consider are stopping times is true. To show that they are (for the natural filtration), show that the event $[\tau\leqslant t]$ depends only on $(X_u)_{u\leqslant t}$.

Comment: For the stopping time $\tau:=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}\colon S_n=0\}$, I suppose Did is assuming that $p=q$.  For in the general case, Doob's optional stopping theorem implies that $E[N_{\tau\wedge n}]=E[N_0]=1$, whence $E[S_{\tau\wedge n}]=E[\tau\wedge n](p-q)+1$.  And $E[S_\tau]=0$ only when $\tau$ is finite with probability one, which in turn requires that $p\leqslant q$. @Did

Comment: But he is right of course.  There is no general result for all $\tau$ here.  In the example $\tau:=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}\colon S_n=0\}$, with $p=q$, there is no convergence in $L^1$, while in the example $\tau:=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}\colon S_n\in\{-a,b\}\}$, or even the simpler example where $\tau$ is constant, there is convergence in $L^1$. @Did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) By independence,
\begin{equation*} E\Bigg[\bigg(\frac{q}{p}\biggr)^{X_{t+1}}\Bigg|\mathscr{F}_t\Biggr]=E\Bigg[\bigg(\frac{q}{p}\biggr)^{X_{t+1}}\Biggr]=\bigg(\frac{q}{p}\biggr)p+\bigg(\frac{q}{p}\biggr)^{-1}q=p+q=1.
\end{equation*}
Also, $E[E[S_{t+1}]|\mathscr{F}_t]=E[S_{t+1}]$ simply because $E[S_{t+1}]$ is a constant.  Now
\begin{align*}
E[N_{t+1}|\mathscr{F}_t]&=E[S_{t+1}|\mathscr{F}_t]-E[E[S_{t+1}]|\mathscr{F}_t]\\ &=
E[S_t+X_{t+1}|\mathscr{F}_t]-E[S_{t+1}]\\ &=E[S_t|\mathscr{F}_t]+E[X_{t+1}|\mathscr{F}_t]-E[S_{t+1}]\\ &=S_t+E[X_{t+1}]-E[S_t]-E[X_{t+1}]\\ &=N_t,
\end{align*} the fourth equality because $S_t$ is $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable, and so $E[S_t|\mathscr{F}_t]=S_t$, and because $X_{t+1}$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_t$, and so $E[X_{t+1}|\mathscr{F}_t]=E[X_{t+1}]$.

As to the second question, I do not understand what you mean.  If $\tau$ is a stopping time, $S_{\tau}$ is merely a random variable not a sequence, so what should converge in $L^1$?

Comment: $S^\tau$ is the process given by $S^\tau_n:=S_{n\wedge \tau}$. Assume we define $\tau:=\min\{n:X_n\in\{-a,b\}\}$ then define $S^\tau:=M$. M is a martingale and $\sup E|M_n|\le a\vee b<\infty$, therefore the limes exists by convergence theorem. But it does not converge in $L^1$, why?